# single click for getting xText editor support

Tags: java, xtext

In my current work, I want  provide  xText editor support ( because of its code completion, syntax high-lighting)  to the  programmers  of  my  domain specific language. I have written grammar in xText.

To provide  xText editor support,  I am going to provide programmers with   full eclipse IDE  with  xText plugin installed (available on xText website).   However, I get xText editor facility at the cost of the the following manual manual steps  (as discussed in 5 mins xText tutorial).

1. The programmers  have to go to File -> New -> Project - >  xText  Project
2. The  programmers have to replace  “hello world” example grammars by my language grammar.
3. They have to go to  RunAs -> Generate Xtext Artifacts.
4. Finally, they have to do : run -> Eclipse Application  to  take editor support . So, they  can write  dsl specification.

My  question is that is there **any way, which can atomize (with minimum effort)  these tasks (any scripting or any other thing) in a single click?**

Comment: Those steps are just meant for *testing* the plugin, not actual usage.  You should be able to install your grammar into eclipse permanently.

Comment: Thanks Sam. But, how could I install my grammar into eclipse plugin. Any suggestions/pointers?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used xtext; I would imagine it's somewhere in the plugin's context menus, though.

Answer (score 7):

OK I'm really not sure I understand your question.  So I'll re-state what I *think* you're asking, and answer that.  Apologies if I've misunderstood - please let me know.

So - I think you're saying:

1. You've developed an xtext grammar for your language
2. You want your users to be able to use the editor xtext has generated for the language
3. right now, the only way you know how to do this is to have your users emulate what you did (install xtext, create a new project,
   copy in your grammar, run the generator, create a runtime instance &
   then finally create files in your DSL)

You want to fix step 3.  So your users can just create a new project then create a new file with your DSL extension and start editing.

***If that's correct*** then the easiest approach is:

1. Select `File->Export...->Plug-in Development->Deployable Features` & click Next
2. Select your DSL project in the list of features (`<your.dsl>.sdk`)
3. Select a directory for the resulting repository and click `Finish`

Eclipse will generate an installable feature for you in the target dir.  You then need to make the repository dir available to your users by publishing somewhere they can access.  This is your `Repository URL`.

Your users then need to:

1. Install a standard eclipse distribution (the modeling tools one is suitable)
2. Select `Help->Install New Software`
3. Click `Add` to add a new repository, and enter your `Repository URL`
4. Select your feature in the list & install

From there they can create new projects & files.  If they create a file with your DSL extension, your xtext-generated editor will be loaded automatically.

You can make their job even easier by generating an eclipse product.  To do that you'll first need to create a product specification then use the `File->Export->Plugin Development->Eclipse Product`.  That will create a standalone eclipse IDE with your plugin pre-installed.  So your users can just install and go.  There's a good tutorial [here](http://kthoms.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/setting-up-a-rcp-product-for-a-dsl/) for this.

hth.

Answer (score 1):

There are three options that would do such automation for you:

1- Use a general *macro recording* software such as [`AutoHotkey`](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [`Sikuli Script`](http://www.sikuli.org/), so you can record these steps and replay them back. You can find similar software as well in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_macro_recorder_software)

2- Use *eclipse* macro plug-in such as [`Practically Macro`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/files/), which is an open source plugin for eclipse

3- Write your own implementation using Java [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class which simply can generate events that are needed for automation such as `keyPress`, `mousePress` and `mouseMove`

Comment: Although in general this is a helpful response, the question asker is using an incorrect sequence for deploying Xtext projects. Suggesting a way to automate this sequence is a very bad idea here.